# CFLAGS in Linux kernel makefiles: which one is used when?

Tags: linux-kernel, make

I'm not familiar with Makefiles, I can kinda understand them, but with the Linux Kernel I have a question.

(Using 3.7.1, Patched with BFS so line numbers may be a bit off)

On line 248

```
HOSTCFLAGS   = -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer
```

Is this passed to all the Makefiles?

Then on Lines 349 and 352 Respectively

```
CFLAGS_MODULE   =
....
CFLAGS_KERNEL   =
....
CFLAGS_GCOV = -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

I'm guessing `CFLAGS_MODULE` is passed to things built as a module, and the next is specific to the kernel itself? And `CFLAGS_GCOV` is for debugging and profiling?

Then there are a bunch of KBUILD_CFLAGS

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -fno-stack-protector)
```

I'm guessing the previous line removes those options, and the next line adds?

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls
```

I haven't found a good tutorial about this either.

Comment: What have you tried? The very first search result I got is [Using Variables in the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Variables).

Comment: The Problem is I can't for the life of me figure out the general idea of what values are used where.

Comment: Yes, the Linux Makefiles are a real mess ;-) There are many different compilations: Build tools that run on the machine doing the build, compile stuff that goes in modules, compile stuff that isn't modules should cover the three macros you cite. Take a tour at http://www.kernelnewbies.org, that should quench your thirst for knowledge.